# After update to Windows 8.1 brightness isn't working (changing)

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, windows-8.1

I just updated my Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 by Windows Store and I have some problems. My notebook is an Acer Aspire Timelinex 3820TG and I know it's little old for Windows 8 but I installed it anyway and the laptop works fine (I updated my HDD to SSD). Now I just updated Windows and I have problem with changing brightness on my dedicated graphic card (Ati HD 5650). First I can changing brightness with <kbd>fn</kbd> + keys but It just changing level in OS without any actual change in brightness. I tried reinstalling drivers, then installed drivers for my card from Acer that were compatible with Windows 7 and there is. When I switched to my integrated card changing brightness works. I think the problem is with drivers but I don't know how to get it working.

Bonus question: I have another problem (but this one is not so important). Does anyone knows what `msietxghh.exe` is doing? Everytime when my system runs (after update) I get message that this program stops working but I just cancel and looks everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you guessed it right, the problem is with the drivers,

I had an Acer Aspire P3-171 with  Windows 8.1 64-bit. For me the problem was with the  Intel VGA 10.x driver. I dig all the drivers of 10.x , nothing worked but  9.x , 9.17.10.2932 worked for me

Try finding 9.x version of your Intel VGA driver, un-install the currently installed drivers,

or you can navigate Control Panel > Device Manager > Display Adapters > Intel HD Graphics 4000 > Driver > Update Driver > Browse my computer and there you will see a list of drivers, try switching in between and see if anything works for you

[here is the link](http://www.programmerfish.com/unable-to-change-brightness-after-upgrading-to-windows-8-1-solved/#.UmfSZXDQlq8) which gives many solutions o this famous problem in detail

Comment: You might want to make it clearer in the answer itself that its your personal blog. In addition, its not loading for me. I'd also note the OP is using an ATI card, so your solution may not be valid

Comment: This solution works aswell with an ATI card. I just used it on my laptop and it saved my day. I selected a 9.x version instead of the 10.x installed and everything works fine again. Seems like a bug in the latest version and community is waiting for an Intel fix. Have a look at https://communities.intel.com/thread/45614?start=0&tstart=0 for example, there's many threads like it on their forum.

Answer (score 0):

I also same problem after update Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, the brightnes key does not work.
I use the notebook sumsung series 5 ultrabook.
Now I have the solution.
Step 1 : go to Charm Bar Menu using Search "SW Update", click "SW Update" program to run.
Step 2 : if SW Update can not run (may some problem during install windows 8.1) 
go to website http://www.samsung.com/us/windows-8-pcs/update.html > Select a category "Notebook"

> click "Firmware and Driver" button to download "SWUpdate_2.1.21.0.ZIP" program > upzip and install
>   Step 3 : run by Step 1 again now SW Update is work, it update bios and drivers, waiting ultil finish (1 - 2 hour), 
>   the brightnes key is worked now.

Answer (score 0):

Rollback the Intel driver to 'system generic driver' provided with Windows and then restart your pc.
After that go to device manager again -> display -> and update your driver again.